# Segmentation Fault when returning an object field from a function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I am getting segmentation fault when I am returning l-value or r-value reference of object field from a function. Can anyone please explain me? I have included the code that I wrote.

```
int randomItem1(const vector<IntCell>& x) { // works fine
    return x[0].read();
```

The code above works fine. However, the following code gives me segmentation fault.

```
const int& randomItem2(const vector<IntCell>& x) { // segmentation fault
    return x[0].read();

int&& randomItem3(const vector<IntCell>& x) { // segmentation fault
    return x[0].read();
```

IntCell class definition:

```
class IntCell {
private:
    int storedValue;
public:
    IntCell(int val):storedVal{val} {}
    int read() const {
        return storedVal;
    }
};
```

Edit:
I have included the class definition for IntCell.

Comment: Ask yourself: you're a returning a reference to *what*? What does `read()` return?

Comment: when you return a reference or pointer, you have to make sure it lives, when you dereference it

Comment: if `read` returns a reference your code should be fine, if it returns a value then there is a duplicate. What is `read` ?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope?rq=1

Comment: Show the `IntCell::read` definition. Better yet, make a [mre].

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I have included the definition of my IntCell class.